# In Maul Lockdown by Joe Schreiber, how did Maul know his opponent used an amphistaff?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-maul, yuuzhan-vong

Given that at that point in time, the Yuuzhan Vong hadn’t attacked yet, and that the amphistaff is the signiture weapon of the Yuuzhan Vong, how would Maul have known the weapon was an amphistaff?

Comment: Because the author forgot that Maul hadn't read to the end of the book